# the meaning of "but neither survived her"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

What is the meaning of the following bolded expression? What is the structure of it?

> She assembled an all-female company at this time and established a
>   school around 1908, **but neither survived her**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**if you are survived by someone, they are still alive after you have died**

*Santos is survived by his wife of 49 years*

What author meant is that both companies did not stay active after her death.